# « Compatible de » ou « compatible avec »

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

Je voudrais vérifier si **« de »** utilisé avec **« compatible »** est correct.

Est-ce qu'il faut plutôt dire « compatible **avec** Windows 10 », ou « compatible **de** Windows 10 » ?

**EDIT :** Je sens que la question parait floue. Je précise donc quelques points :

- Je cherche à exprimer le fait de savoir si un logiciel donné (par exemple Microsoft Word) est compatible d'un système d'exploitation donné (ici Microsoft Windows 10).
- Je ne me préoccupe pas de savoir si c'est pour un ordinateur donné ou non, je veux savoir, en général, si pour tous les systèmes sous Windows 10 (PC ou non), ce logiciel en est compatible. Si je suis sur un téléphone Nokia, ma question reste valide

Answer (score 6):

**Compatible et compatibilité s'emploient avec *avec* lors que l'on fait référence à une des choses (ou personnes) *compatible* avec d'autres.**

> La compatibilité **avec** cette version est difficile.
>
> Le logiciel compatible **avec** mon ordinateur.

On peut aussi employer pour l'adjectif: *vis à vis de*, *par rapport à*, *pour* , envers (moins fréquent).

Pour le substantif, on peut aussi employer *au sujet de* (passe-partout).

Lorsqu'on emploie compatibilité, non pas d'un objet identifié avec d'autres, mais d'un **ensemble d'objets entre eux**, on utilise justement **entre**:

> La compatibilité **entre** ces versions.

[Voir des exemples ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compatible).

Dans le groupe *une version compatible de Windows 10*, ***de* relie une version et Windows 10, et n'est pas relié à compatible.** Cette formulation aurait besoin d'être terminée:

> Une version compatible de Windows 10 **pour/avec mon ordinateur** = Une version
>   de Windows 10 compatible pour/avec mon ordinateur.

Answer (score 4):

Si la question est de savoir si le logiciel fonctionne sur Windows 10, seule la formulation utilisant "avec" est valide:

> Ce logiciel est compatible avec Windows 10
>   Ce logiciel fonctionne avec Windows 10
>   Ce logiciel fonctionne sur Windows 10

Ici, on dit que "Windows 10" et "Ce logiciel" sont compatibles. On ne peut pas utiliser "de" dans cette construction.
Mémo: Si on enlève "compatible", la phrase n'a plus aucun sens.

La formulation utilisant "de" ne veut pas dire la même chose:

> Ce logiciel nécessite une version compatible de Windows.
>   Ce logiciel nécessite une version de Windows compatible.

Ici, on dit que "Ce logiciel" n'est pas compatible avec toutes les versions de "Windows". Il faut donc choisir une version de Windows qui est compatible avec le logiciel. On ne peut pas utiliser "avec" dans cette construction. Le mot "de" est associé à "version" et non à "compatible".
Mémo: Si on enlève "compatible", la phrase garde un sens.

Comment: Il faudrait mettre en évidence le fait que l'on ne dit pas "Ce logiciel est compatible de Windows 10" pour taire toute ambiguïté dans la question/réponse. L'OP n'a pas cité les phrases en entier, dire que "les deux sont corrects" complique la compréhension de la réponse, amha.

Comment: Merci @Limo, j'ai pris en compte la remarque :)

Comment: Dans la deuxième phrase la préposition *de* s'attache à « version » pas à « compatible ». Répondre que les deux sont corrects à la question posée est trompeur. Seul « compatible avec » est correct. On notera que « compatib**ilité** de » et « compatib**ilité** *avec* » sont par contre tous les deux corrects (et ont des sens différents).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Dans la question, rien n'est précisé. On ne connait pas le contexte, donc aucun moyen de savoir ce qui est voulu. Les 2 phrases correspondre à ce qui est demandé...

Comment: Réponse éditée suite aux modifications de la question.

Answer (score 1):

En fait, vous ne prenez pas la chose du bon côté.

ON dit, Windows et le logiel Truc sont compatibles. On ne devrait pas dire qu'un logiciel est compatible à Windows. On dit que le logiciel et Windows sont compatibles. Regardez la définition de *Compatible* dans le dictionnaire au lieu d'écouter à droite et à gauche. Le dico est ce sur quoi tout le monde est censé s'entendre. [La référence](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/compatible/17628#GHs2KWzTyrA5AEmA.99) :

> compatible
>   adjectif
>   (latin médiéval *compatibilis*)
>       Définitions
>       Expressions
>       Synonymes
>    Qui peut exister en même temps, s'accorder avec quelque chose d'autre ; conciliable : *Leurs caractères ne sont pas compatibles*.
>       Se dit d'appareils doués de compatibilité.
>       Se dit de polymères présentant une bonne miscibilité.

Mais en principe on dit "compatible à/avec quelque chose" mais "de" est complètement faux. Regardez la définition de "De" et vous comprendrez.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. « Regardez la définition de Compatible dans le dictionnaire au lieu d'écouter à droite et à gauche. » n'est pas vraiment le genre de contenu attendu dans les réponses. Surtout quand la « référence » donné, en l’occurrence un seul dictionnaire qui n'est pas généralement considéré comme le meilleur. Par ailleurs cette réponse n'apporte rien de plus, et est moins complète que celles déjà données. [Le fonctionnement de French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour), le [Help Center](https://french.stackexchange.com/help).