# Le logiciel, que fait-il généralement : un effort continu ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, terminologie, informatique, transitivité

Dans un [article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?N=2&id=1643) sur le choix de la préposition (*sous/avec*) pour introduire le système d'exploitation en fonction dans un contexte, on donne l'exemple suivant :

> Ce logiciel [travaille](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3902) sous Windows 10. (*BDL*)

---

- Est-ce [*travailler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/travailler) pour l'idée d'effort continu similaire à
  l'exécution (d'un programme ; *il travaille*) ou le sens est-il incomplet sans ce complément introduit par la préposition *sous* (pour le système en fonction ; *il s'inscrit dans le cadre de...*) même si c'était intransitif ; qu'est-ce que l'exemple veut dire ?
- Un *logiciel*, est-ce qu'on dit que ça s'[*exécute*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8369641) comme un
  programme ou est-ce que ce sont seulement les instructions du
  programme dont on peut dire qu'on les exécute ou qu'elles s'exécutent ?
- Quel verbe est-il le plus usuel avec le *logiciel*, sans
  complément ni idée de [compatibilité](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17979), pour en dire la même chose, à son échelle, que lorsqu'on dit d'un programme qu'il s'exécute ; qu'est-ce que ça fait ou qu'est-ce qu'on lui fait faire au juste, est-ce que ça *roule/marche/tourne/travaille/[fonctionne (sous)](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365133)*  ou ça ne fait que *s'utiliser*, et pourquoi ?

Comment: _Travailler_ comme traduction de _work_ dans ce contexte me semble inusité en France, même dans mon milieu professionnel pourtant très porté sur un jargon plein d'anglicismes. C'est peut-être différent au Québec.

Comment: Je me méfierais de l'office québécois de la langue française dorénavant ;)

Comment: Ils ne donnent pas de références quand ils disent qu'un "logiciel qui travaille" est une bonne formulation, voilà ce qui me chiffonne, outre le fait que j'évite les anglicismes, et encore plus ceux qui tordent le sens de mots français existants. Ils peuvent faire erreur, mais j'attends d'un bon support de référence qu'ils ne se mouille pas trop quand il y a une possible erreur.

Comment: Ma question ne porte pas sur la traduction de quoi que ce soit et il n'y a pas de tag _intransitivité_. Je décide de ce sur quoi porte ma question. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En 30 ans d'informatique, c'est bien la première fois que je vois "travailler"... Pour moi le terme habituel en geek vernaculaire est "tourner":  *"Ça tourne sous Windows ton truc?"*(*).  "Tourner" peut s'utiliser tout seul: "Si le CPU-mètre est à 100%, c'est qu'il y a un logiciel qui tourne".

Sinon, oui, on peut dire qu'un logiciel *s'exécute*.

(*) Bizarrement, cette question s'applique aussi bien à une application (qui a besoin de Windows comme support) qu'à un matériel particulier (qui fournit un support pour Windows).

Comment: Considérez-vous que _fonctionner/tourner_ sous avec le logiciel est une extension de sens, ou avez-vous un commentaire sur le lien sous _fonctionner sous_ en question ? Supposons qu'il y a longtemps, devant un pointeur devenu sablier sous Système 7, quelqu'un ait dit que l'ordinateur _pense_ ou _réfléchit_ et qu'on doit attendre. Qqc. est _en cours de_ qqc. Ma réflexion repose en partie sur l'idée qu'il y a un lexique plus technique et un lexique plus usuel et que l'informatique n'en est plus à ses débuts alors je devrais posséder un vocabulaire plus usuel pour décrire ce qui se passe.../2

Comment: Avez-vous un commentaire sur l'idée _bien fonctionner avec/pour_, dans le sens d'être bien adapté à la tâche à accomplir ? Dites-vous qu'un pinceau _fonctionne bien_ pour peindre, ou que _ça fonctionne bien_ peindre avec ce pinceau ? Si je dis _ça irait mieux si tu utilisais telle application pour faire telle chose_ la question ne se pose pas, mais je cherche des manières d'exprimer ce qui précède avec le logiciel et l'application, comme "outil usuel"... Merci.

Comment: Non, je ne sais pas pourquoi on utilise "sous"... Surtout qu'on utilise aussi (mais moins fréquemment), "sur". C'est peut être une différence entre les informaticiens (sous-istes) et les utilisateurs (sur-istes). Mais les Linuxiens plaisantent en disant qu'ils travaillent "avec" Linux alors que les autres sont "sous" Windows (collaboration choisie v.s. domination imposée).

Comment: Il y aura un vocabulaire usuel quand les utilisateurs prendront le pouvoir linguistique... Certains mots sont vites adoptés quand ils sont bons: souris, ordinateur, logiciel, calculette... D'autres sont de gros échecs, comme bogue. Ce qui me frappe, c'est l'absence complète en informatique des mots composés en verbe-c.o.d., si fréquents ailleurs: tire-bouchon, lave-vaisselle, essuie-glace...

Comment: @xenoid Absence complète est exagéré: il y a au moins « pare-feu » et le plus rare « ramasse-miettes » (*garbage collector*).

Comment: C'est l'exception qui confirme la règle puisque ce ne sont pas des mots qui on été créés pour l'informatique... a-t-on déjà vu un nettoie-registre, un édite-image, un cherche-fichier? Et d'ailleurs pourquoi tous ces mots en -eur, jamais en -euse, en -oir ou en -oire?

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi, c'est un anglicisme maladroit, par paresse des traducteurs, ou par traductions semi-automatiques.

Avant l'informatique, on parlait de "travailler" quand il s'agissait de choses, dans des expressions comme:

- Le bois *travaille*.
- Cette idée *me travaille*.

Traduisant donc apparemment une idée de force qui "travaille" justement, produisant des changements (forme, etc...)

Ce logiciel travaille...

Pour dire effectivement: Ce logiciel s'exécute sous.../fonctionne sous...

ça ne me semble pas du tout avoir eu des précédents dans la langue avant cet exemple. It works = directement traduit par "il travaille" sans réfléchir...
L'ennui c'est que souvent les traductions automatiques sont reprises, par des personnes qui pensent que c'est comme ça qu'il faut traduire, et c'est comme ça qu'on a un barbarisme de plus.

Comment: C'est comme la terrible "traduction" "*library*" => "*librairie*" qui est encore beaucoup trop utilisée (et qui a pas l'air de vouloir partir). Dans ce contexte "*it works on...*" a le sens de "*il marche/ il fonctionne sous...*".

Comment: Je ne rejette rien, j'ai mentionné les forces.

Comment: Pardon de vous avoir vexée, je ne fais qu'exprimer une opinion, de plus j'ai ajouté un ;-) Je vais être clair: ce que je dis sur ce site n'engage que ma propre opinion, j'essaye de donner des références, si je dis une bêtise, ça n'engage que moi mais j'ai le droit de l'exprimer. Je respecte l'opinion des autres, merci de respecter les miennes.Surtout quand ma volonté n'est d'agresser personne parce que je mets un ;-) On peut parler d'une façon légère,on n'est pas obligé en permanence de se battre en duel avec tout le monde. Le clin d’œil veut en général dire "je plaisante" ou "j'exagère un peu

Answer (score 1):

Comme les avis déjà exprimés, je pense qu'il s'agit d'une erreur car « travailler » ne peut pas traduire *to work* ici.

Quant à l'origine de cette erreur, je pencherais plutôt pour un manque de contrôle lors de l'inclusion récente de cette page sur le site de l'oqlf qui par ailleurs est plutôt d'une grande rigueur et d'excellente qualité.

Il est aussi fort possible que cet article ait été rédigé par un anglophone, comme pourrait peut-être le laisser penser un deuxième anglicisme deux lignes plus loin:

> mon ordinateur **performe** bien

Contrairement à « travailler sous »,  « performer » est cependant est devenu assez courant en français.

Edit: **l'oqlf a reconnu et vient de corriger cette erreur** sur l'utilisation de **travailler**. En revanche, contrairement à l'Académie française qui [déconseille performer](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/performer), l'oqlf [accepte et justifie son utilisation](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1399950).

Comment: Le *performer* de l'oqlf n'est justifié que dans le cadre d'une *performance*, ce qui ne s'applique pas du tout à un ordinateur (sauf si on parle de sa puissance par exemple), ça reste donc bien un (très grossier) anglicisme dans ce contexte

Comment: Merci pour le suivi !

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. De rien, l'oqlf est remarquablement réactif ! PS : la valse des pseudos de certains utilisateurs de French.SE me donne le tournis ...  ;-)

Comment: Moi aussi parfois ça me travaille ;) De Joyeuses Fêtes !